# Плавное изменение объекта после изменения контента внутри

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Допустим, есть кнопка со своим стилем:

```
<a href="" class="action-button">SomeText</a>
```

Когда я при помощи jQuery меняю текст кнопки на SomeTextSomeText, то кнопка становится шире, но без анимации, рывком. Пытался выставлять `transition: width .25s ease-in-out;`, но это не дало эффекта. Собственно, вопрос заключается в том, как можно определить плавность изменения текста внутри элемента при помощи js(желательно без fadeIn/fadeOut или при помощи css)?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// заменяет текст в ссылке
function changeLinkText( link, newText ){
     const wrapper = link.firstChild;

     // для того чтобы transition работал ширина должна быть не auto;
     link.style.width = link.offsetWidth + "px";  // выставляем текущую ширину
     wrapper.innerHTML = newText; //изменяем текст в ссылке (это увеличит ширину дива но ширина ссылки сохранится как есть)
     link.style.width = wrapper.offsetWidth + "px"; //выставляем новую ширину ссылки (это запустит transition).
 }
 
//просто для демонстрации
const link = document.querySelector('.link');
setTimeout( ()=>changeLinkText( link, "Hello World"), 1000 );
setTimeout( ()=>changeLinkText( link, "short" ), 2000 );
setTimeout( ()=>changeLinkText( link, "long long long before end of animation"), 2100 );

setTimeout( ()=>changeLinkText( link, "short again"), 3000 );
```

```css
.link{
  transition: width 0.25s;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.link > div{
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<a class="link"><div>test</div></a>
```